# Using Postman with gRPC

Tags: c#, postman, grpc, visual-studio-2022

I've got the following "hello world" gRPC serivice working in a c#, VS 2022 console client calling both http and https endpoints; but I get errors when using Postman for Windows (ver 9.21.3) calling the same endpoints.

proto:

```
service Greeter {
  // Sends a greeting
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply);
}

// The request message containing the user's name.
message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}

// The response message containing the greetings.
message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}
```

post http://localhost:5046/Greeter/SayHello

body > raw > {"Name" : "testing grpc http"}

postman response -> "Parse Error: The server returned a malformed response"

postman console -> "Error: Parse Error: Expected HTTP/" c# grpc server console -> none

---

post https://localhost:7046/Greeter/SayHello

body > raw > {"Name" : "testing grpc HTTPS"} postman response       -> "Error: socket hang up"

c# grpc server console -> "HTTP/2 over TLS was not negotiated on an HTTP/2-only endpoint."

Anyone having success with the c#/VS2022/Postman stack?

**UPDATE**

I'm now creating my request via the link posted by @LaurentGabiot here:
https://blog.postman.com/postman-now-supports-grpc/

and am now getting the same error for both of my http/https endpoints:

**"Error: Invalid protocol: https"**

In their sample, their endpoints are: "grpcb.in:9000" whatever that means. Not sure how to do that in Vs2022/c#.

Note: I'm leaving my original errors (above) in case someone else creates their request the same way that I did.

Comment: I might be wrong, but don't you need the beta version of Postman for gRPC support?  Have you followed the steps at [https://blog.postman.com/postman-now-supports-grpc/](https://blog.postman.com/postman-now-supports-grpc/) ? Did you upload your proto file?

Comment: Hi @LaurentGabiot, I don't believe there is a "beta version" of Postman itself, but instead when you select "New", you choose the "gRPC [beta]" option.

Comment: @LaurentGabiot, Your link was useful tho because I wasn't creating my request correctly and now I'm getting a different error: "Error: Invalid protocol: https". I posted a comment to the article on postman's site. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just type the URL without scheme as the server URL, i.e. `localhost:5046`.